# Nginx Laravel config returning 403

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I've set up a new Laravel 5.7 site on a VPS. I had previously run the site locally using `valet` with no issues. However, now when I navigate to my `dashboard` route using `https://mysite.mydomain.net/dashboard`, I'm getting a `403` error returned by nginx (there's no laravel errors, so I'm assuming it never gets to laravel at all).

Other paths that hit other routes with a similar structure don't seem to be affected.

I've tried running `php artisan route:clear` to make sure it's not hitting an older cached routing.

The route is simple:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return "yo";
})->name('dashboard'); // returns 403
```

Almost exactly the same route returns the expected result with no issue:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return "test";
})->name('test'); // returns "test"
```

Here's the nginx config:

```
server {

         # Log files for Debugging
         access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log;
         error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log;

         # Webroot Directory for Laravel project
         root /var/www/mysite/public;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;

         # Your Domain Name
         server_name mysite.mydomain.net;

         location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
         }

         # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
         location ~ \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
         }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.mydomain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.mydomain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = mysite.mydomain.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


         listen 80;
         listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
         server_name mysite.mydomain.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Does laravel authentication throw an nginx 403 error? I would expect it to at least show a laravel error message-- and besides, there's no middleware on this route. What could be going on?

The nginx error log shows:

```
2018/10/30 20:46:48 [error] 19626#19626: *2201 directory index of "/var/www/mysite/public/dashboard/" is forbidden, client: 98.146.255.247, server: mysite.mydomain.net, request: "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1", host: "rem$
```

Comment: sound like your problem is that you do have a folder named dashboard in your site root. `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` doesn't get to call the php and nginx tries to serve content in $uri/

Comment: You could get rid of the $uri/ in this line `try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;`
But it's a much better idea not to have your app a site root to avoid those confusions

Comment: @AntonyGibbs true, I have a `public/dashboard` that holds my mixed down css / js etc. assets.

Comment: @AntonyGibbs -- that worked, removing the `$uri/` fixed the issue. Please make that your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sound like you have a folder named dashboard in your site root.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

doesn't get to call the php as nginx tries to serve content in $uri/

As a quick fix you could get rid of the $uri/ in this line

```
try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
```

But it's a much better idea not to have your app a site root to avoid those confusions.
You could put css, etc... in a folder /assets and change the line to

```
try_files $uri $uri/ assets/$uri /index.php?$query_string;
```

or something like that

```
location /assets {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location / {
    try_files /index.php?$query_string =503;
}
```

don't forget (before any other location as order matters)

```
# protect hidden files/folders ex: .git
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `php artisan cache:clear`.

---

I actually experienced the same thing. Wierdly enough, I somehow 'massaged' the error out, by writing `dd( 'Blah' );` at the top of my `web.php` (routes file). After I had done that, I moved the `dd`-line a couple of lines down (loading the problematic URL every time I moved it). In the end, then the `dd( 'Blah' )` was in the bottom of the file, - and all my routes were working (so it *must* have been some caching of some sort). I had also tried to clear the cache previous to doing this.
... I have no idea why it worked. But it did. I had the error for 45 minutes, before I did this.

If that doesn't help, then perhaps check the content of `/var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log;` (as you write in the Nginx-configuration).

If that doesn't help, then try changing the route from `/dashboard` to `/newdashboard` temporarily, to see if the error follows along. 
... Or you can try and copy the `/test`-route and rename it, to see if that would work. 
... Or you can change the order of your routes.

I also had another problem like this, that appeared to be a middleware-problem, - but that was pretty long ago. I'm just mentioning it, so you have a couple of places to check.

But I can't see anything wrong with what you've written. So I'd put my money on the order of the routes, - or something else running on the server, occupying that URL.